# Convert files to UTF-8 : Get-Content : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to convert large files of dat files to UTF-8 to load them into a database (the files have Japanese characters on them). Largest file is 17 GB and whole directory is 34 GB. Below is my PowerShell script.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'E:\datamig_bkp_SCMDB\data\bigfiles' -Recurse |
         ? {Test-Path $_.FullName -PathType Leaf}
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $content = Get-Content $file.FullName
    $content | Out-File $file.FullName -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Im getting below error:

```
Get-Content : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
At line:3 char:16
+     $content = Get-Content $file.FullName
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-Content], OutOfMemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderContentReadError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't read large files into memory. Write the output to a new (temporary) file, then remove the original and move the temp file to its place.

```
$tmp = 'C:\path\to\temp.txt'
Get-ChildItem 'E:\datamig_bkp_SCMDB\data\bigfiles' -Recurse | Where-Object {
    -not $_.PSIsContainer
} | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_.FullName
    Get-Content $file | Out-File $tmp -Encoding UTF8
    Remove-Item $file -Force
    Move-Item $tmp $file
}
```

As TheIncorrigible1 pointed out in the comments, the code could be streamlined a little when you have PowerShell v3 or newer:

```
$tmp = 'C:\path\to\temp.txt'
Get-ChildItem 'E:\datamig_bkp_SCMDB\data\bigfiles' -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_.FullName
    Get-Content $file | Out-File $tmp -Encoding UTF8
    Remove-Item $file -Force
    Move-Item $tmp $file
}
```

Comment: Instead of `Where-Object`, it'd be more readable to use the `-File` switch.  You can also pipe a `FileInfo` object directly to `Get-Content`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 The parameter `-File` was introduced with PowerShell v3. I prefer to keep my answers backward-compatible, so I tend to avoid newer features unless the question states that the user is running a recent-enough version. As for piping file objects into `Get-Content`: I fail to see the advantage here, since each file should be processed separately, and the full path is required for moving the temp file after deleting the original file. I wasn't sure if the information in the `FileInfo` object survives the deletion of the file, so I took the safe approach.

Comment: It just makes for more readable code using a pipeline versus using positional arguments, imo.  The `FileInfo` object is retained after the item itself is removed as an FYI.  `$_ | Get-Content | Out-File -FilePath $tmp -Encoding utf8` etc.

Comment: I don't disagree on the readability aspect. I still emphasize on compatibility, though, b/c that way the answer is useful to a broader audience.